# R data.table. interface to on-disk fst files: fst_table

Tags: r, serialization, data.table, fst

I want to use for a large dataset the fst_table function from the package "fstpackage" found here: https://github.com/fstpackage/fsttable.

```
devtools::install_github("fstpackage/fsttable")
library(fsttable)
nr_of_rows <- 1e6
x <- data.table::data.table(X = 1:nr_of_rows, Y = LETTERS[1 + (1:nr_of_rows) %% 26])
fst::write_fst(x, "1.fst")
ft <- fst_table("1.fst")
```

I can extract rows and columns of the created file, however, is it possible to do operations like:

```
ft[X == 1,]
```

as in a standard data.table? or can I create a key of this data.table for fast serialization? My goal with this is to extract data using values of the columns without loading all the dataset into the memory.

Comment: You could also try an indexed SQL table with `RSQLite`.

Comment: I'm a big fan of `data.table`, but have you considered [vroom](https://github.com/r-lib/vroom)?

Comment: Gonna check vroom, sound promising. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Original

Unfortunately, `fsttable` only works to load the dataset and select columns/rows. Although in the [documentation](https://github.com/fstpackage/fsttable) of the package says:

> This `fst_table` can be used as a regular *data.table* object

The reality is that regular *data.table* operations such as the one you mentioned can not be performed (at least with version `0.1.3`). The main reason behind it is that we are in fact not working with a *data.table* object, but rather with a data.table interface:

```
> class(ft)
[1] "datatableinterface" "data.table"         "data.frame"
```

However, the data from the `fsttable` object can be "pulled" as a vector  and then be filtered. Following your example:

```
ft[,list(X)]$X
ft[,list(X)][['X']]
ft[,list(X)] %>% pull()
```

And then filtered, for example:

```
> ft[,list(X)]$X[ft[,list(X)]$X==1]
[1] 1
```

I presume there should be an easy way to convert a `fsttable` object to a genuine `data.table` by pulling each variable and then binding all them together.

### Edit

Actually, `read_fst()` of `fst` package (available in CRAN, by the same author) has an argument to upload datasets as `data.table`, no need to `fsttable` package

```
ft <- read_fst("ft", as.data.table = T)

# if only a few columns are desired
ft <- read_fst("ft", columns = c("X"), as.data.table = T)

# if a tibble is needed
ft <- read_fst("ft", as.data.table = T) %>% as_tibble()
```